# 0.5 to 4.0 hours Timing Circuit

Tags: timing, pir

This is my first electronics project - apologies for the noob question.

I wish to control a power relay, trigged via motion / PIR.  After the PIR triggers the relay, the relay should stay "on" for a user selectable time, of 0.5 to 4.0 hours duration. (approximate, timing does not have to be accurate)

How can I build a end-user-adjustable timing circuit, with that range of time delay? 
e.g it needs a knob the user can turn.

Also, is it realistically feasible to do this without a micro-controller? For learning purposes.

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is RC circuit (with very high time constant) connected to a comparator. Not sure if you would be able to find large enough capacitors, though -- looking at millifarads.

Comment: Well, if you want to do this for learning reasons, the most important thing you'll learn is that it's a royal pain in the ass and there's a reason everyone doing this in 2016 will use a microcontroller. An analog 4-hour delay is infeasible. You could do it with discrete logic, but why?

Comment: The sensible solution will involve a microcontroller. If you must, look at circuits using the 1970s-era CD4060, or if you're really into self-flagellation, maybe 1940s-era [Dekatron](http://www.decadecounter.com/vta/tubepage.php?item=15) tubes.

Comment: lol thanks,  I do usually prefer the hard route, but yes in this case I now understand microcontroller is the way to go.  Thankyou, that is exactly what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't want to use a microcontroller, you might as well take a look at the ubiquitous 555 timer chip.  Here is a circuit that, when activated, will keep the relay energized for a period determined by the capacitor and two resistors on the left side of the schematic:

[image]

The 555 timer only triggers when it's input goes from a high level to low level.  I don't know which way your PIR is set up.  The nice thing about this circuit is that it includes the circuitry to trip on a negative going pulse, or a positive going pulse using the transistor to invert the signal.  The transistor, if needed, can be any NPN type, such as the 2N3904.

With the values shown (where the resistance can vary from 4.3K to 104K depending on the pot setting), the time period is adjustable from 17 minutes to 7 hours.  I figured that using this [555 monostable circuit calculator](http://www.ohmslawcalculator.com/555-monostable-calculator).

The capacitor is what's known as a "supercap", here is one [on Digi-Key](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/elna-america/DHL-5R5D224T/604-1158-ND/3280651).  220mF is the same as 220,000 µF. Note the tolerance is -20% to +80%, so you'll have to play around with the pot to get the right setting.  But even at the extremes of the two values, you should be able to set your desired range.

The TLC555 can only source a maximum of 15 mA, so you will want to use a reed relay.  [This one](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/coto-technology/9007-05-00/306-1062-ND/301696) will operate off of 5V and draw 10 mA.  Note however it is a SPST type (it doesn't have the NC contact like the one in the schematic.)

Comment: Thankyou that looks like a perfect place to start, much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I'd pick a capacitor and resistors for a a 555 timer to get an astable timer with a period of around 2 seconds, then run the output through a 744020 (or 74LS4020, etc.) to get the right period. From there you'll need a driver circuit, since the 744020 won't be able to drive your relay directly.

http://www.ohmslawcalculator.com/555-astable-calculator

The problem is that once you've triggered the output once, you need to stop this so it doesn't keep counting and triggering again every N minutes/hours. That's obviously possible, but adds still more complexity to a circuit that's already excessive for such a simple task.

Or you could come to your senses and use a minimal microcontroller like, say, an ATtiny5 instead.

Comment: Thanks @Jerry. Although It's not a matter of coming to ones senses (which implies prior existing knowledge), it's about learning a *new* field, from zero experience.  As per the comments above, I now understand that avoiding a use of a microprocesser is infeasible though not impossible, which is exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks for the point towards the AT.

Comment: @MtlDev: Yeah (and hopefully you don't take that too seriously--it was intended to be lighthearted) But, (for example) the supercap in tcrosley's circuit is (by itself) about 5 times the price of an ATtiny, which is officially about $1 in quantity 1 (but you can probably get a few samples for free if you ask nicely).

Comment: If you *really* want it to be impractical, program up a ring oscillator and divider in an FPGA (no, I'm *not* recommending this).